# How to use Stereo Effect (VR) and Post Processing (THREE.JS R76)

Tags: three.js, shader, virtual-reality, post-processing

I have a post processing bloom shader running and a VR (virtual reality) conditional stereo effect. They don't seem to want to work together. I am likely just implementing this wrong. Here is the code but where is the mistake?

In my Init()

```
effectPass = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.CopyShader);
bloomPass = new THREE.BloomPass(2);
renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera );

composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);

composer.addPass(renderPass);
composer.addPass(bloomPass);
composer.addPass(effectPass);

effectPass.renderToScreen = true;
renderer.autoClear = false;

if (vr) {
    stereo = new THREE.StereoEffect(renderer);
    stereo.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}
```

In my render()

```
renderer.clear();
composer.render();

renderFrame = requestAnimationFrame(render);
if (vr) { stereo.render(scene, camera); }
else { renderer.render(scene, camera); }
```

Comment: Did you find any answer to this ?

Comment: No :( . It ended up crashing on phones anyways. Worked on laptops though. Never did get the two to work together. If anyone knows the answer to my original question. Feel free to let me know - I will go back and update the software.